# How to reference a table on an Excel worksheet using OPENROWSET?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way to reference a *table* on an Excel worksheet using OPENROWSET?

Referencing a whole sheet works:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 
12.0;Database=D:\Temp\test.xlsm;IMEX=1;HDR=Yes','select * from [Sheet1$]')
```

Referencing a range on sheet works too:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 
12.0;Database=D:\Temp\test.xlsm;IMEX=1;HDR=No','select * from [Sheet1$A1:Z100]')
```

*This is not working... trying to reference Table1*

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 
12.0;Database=D:\Temp\test.xlsm;IMEX=1;HDR=No','select * from [Sheet1$Table1]')
```

NOTE:
If this is not possible, then can anybody suggest a different method, maybe using C#/VB.Net to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If the range named `Table1` was created with the [name box](https://exceljet.net/glossary/name-box) it automatically has global scope. If this is the case just query it without referencing the sheet:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;
Database=D:\Temp\test.xlsm;IMEX=1;HDR=No','select * from [Table1]')
```

If you need `Table1` to have local (sheet) scope then it should be named `SheetName!Table1`, where *SheetName* should be the sheet intended for `Table1`.

Some more info about [opwenrowset and Excel](https://blog.learningtree.com/using-openrowset-to-read-excel-worksheets-from-sql-server-part-2-linked-sql-queries/) and [Named Ranges in Excel](https://exceljet.net/named-ranges).

Comment: Thank you Emilio for looking into this but none of the suggested queries work. For the first one I get "The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'Table1'" and for the second: "Syntax error in FROM clause."